# Are there any security chests on Yavin 4?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

With the release of the Shadow of Revan expansion, I've found a lot of security chests on the new planet Rishi.  However, I haven't seen any on the new planet (moon) Yavin 4.  Are there any?  Specific locations would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Yavin does not have chests.

They decided that flooding it with gathering nodes was enough.